# What happens to rez points when you merge (alpha) forks?

Tags: eclipse-phase

This is a question asked on a french forum: http://www.black-book-editions.fr/forum/index.php?topic=3484.0

Let's say you have a fork (in particular, alpha fork) and you merge. The fork might have accumulated rez points. How do the rez points merge? Are they just added together?

Comment: +1 for good grief, how did I not ask this already?  An interesting and important mechanical question.

Comment: @Tynam Yes, that's exactly what I thought when the guy asked.

Comment: I would keep the higher of the two XP and average out the moxie. It's a good question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On p.384 of the *EP* core rulebook, it states that rez points are awarded *at the end of every story arc, at the break in the action between one adventure and the next*.

With that in mind it's more important what your character did during the course of the story arc than how different forks may have helped him accomplish those feats. So for example, if sending an alpha fork to investigate the abandoned space station helped the character accomplish his objective, the merged character gets a rez point. Basically whatever happened to the alpha fork while it was off doing its thing doesn't matter. What matters is what the character did, whether he had to fork and merge to get the job done or not.

Comment: I see but you mean that it should be the same whatever the time spent between the fork and the merge? What if the alpha fork did things for years and then they merge? We still assume it's the character played that have rez not added by by the fork?

Comment: Or maybe you mean that whatever the case earning Rez points is totally independent from merging and should be only based on objectives accomplished?

Comment: I may not have expressed it well, but my point was that rez points are for the character. To your first comment, if an alpha fork goes off for years, it's not going to merge, because it has become a new character. To your second comment, yes, rez points are for accomplishments made by the character, regardless of how those accomplishments are achieved.